# Extending partition with free space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

So I'm having a problem extending the partiton, I don't have idea what is wrong... 
I create some free space, and than I try to extend some partition with that free space but I just can't click "Extend partition" So what could be the problem? This is on Windows 8.1.

If you know some other way to extend partion (cmd or something), feel free to suggest it.

[image: Here's the picture]

Comment: You want to extend C:, right? Well, the space has to be contiguous aka. form *one* block after merging. You can't use free space that is not adjacent to the partition you want to extend.

Comment: well, than how do I extend it then? How do I create some free space it can use to extend itself?

Comment: It's hard. Basically you need to move the second partition (G:) and its enclosing extended partition to the right. Windows disk management won't allow that because it can potentially break OSes and boot loaders that rely on absolute sectors.

Comment: weeell, is it possible... ?

Comment: Yes, GParted includes this as a trivial task as "Move/Resize".

Comment: Extending C: or Seagate Data G:?

Comment: Extending System C